# Should I list my new app on the google apps marketplace, or is the chrome web store enough?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace

I want to list a new application that will integrate with the Drive UI.  Should I list it on the Google Apps Marketplace?

This seems like an obvious "yes," but the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing) seems to say that I only need to upload a manifest file to the Chrome Web Store.

I've been very confused by seemingly contradictory docs and links across different brands, versions of documentation, etc.  If anyone can share a succinct list of steps to making my app available to install on a Google Apps domain, I'd appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should list your Drive App on the Google Apps marketplace if you want Google Apps Customers use your app. You can list your apps for either Enterprise users or Consumers (gmail and the like) but not both. To list your Drive App in the Marketplace, make sure you specify `"container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE", "GOOGLE_DRIVE"]` in your [manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing#the_manifest_file). Note that you should not specify the `app` member in the manifest as that would make it a consumer app and is not compatible with the Google Apps Marketplace.

We're constantly working to improve our documentation but your feedback is noted.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  This is great confirmation that I'm on the right track.  Overall the documentation is clear, but every so often it assumes I understand something that I don't and so it seems to me like it skips a step.

Comment: To be clear, though: to list my app on the "Google Apps Marketplace," I *do* list it on the "Google Chrome Web Store," but just make sure to specify DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE and GOOGLE_DRIVE in the manifest and omit the `app` property.  Right?